# How do you autoincrement a column in Oracle 11g and previous?

Tags: oracle

I developed application in Oracle 12c  there Id is autoincremented but same application i want to run in oracle11g how to do it. any plugin to autoincrement the Id column

Comment: if it's all PL/SQL you can use a SEQUENCE and just use NEXTVAL to populate the field.

Comment: Share the code that's giving the issue

Answer (score 1):

There's no really easy way, you can probably make it automatic with triggers, but I fear it will just make things worse.

Let's say you have a table TEST

```
CREATE TABLE TEST (
    ID_TEST NUMBER,
    VAL_TEST VARCHAR2(10)
);
```

If you want to automatically set ID_TEST you can:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_TEST_ID START WITH 1 NOCACHE; -- to have single increments
```

then change your inserts adding the ID_TEST column.

```
INSERT INTO TEST (ID_TEST, VAL_TEST) values (SEQ_TEST_ID.NEXTVAL, 'foo');
INSERT INTO TEST (ID_TEST, VAL_TEST) values (SEQ_TEST_ID.NEXTVAL, 'foo');
```

Sure you still have to modify your insert statements, so depending on the number of those this may be or may be not a fast approach.

Comment: "Making it automatic with triggers" is the standard way to accomplish this in versions of Oracle prior to 12c.